# Car Track Boundaries consistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm developing a car game and for the track, I am trying to create boundaries where I set `speed = 0` when it gets to a certain x coordinate on the canvas.

It is a car with turning properties, and I think the coordinates of the car are defined for the center of the uploaded image. Therefore, when it turns stationary toward the edge of the track and goes straight towards it, the speed turns 0 at a certain point.

[image: The image for that]

But when it goes straight ahead and then turns as well, the speed turns 0 at a different point that may be beyond the track.

[image: The image for that]

**[The code for it](http://jsbin.com/wihimopige/2/edit?html,js)**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: when you set the speed to zero, you stop the car... just have it go slower when out of bounds. (http://jsbin.com/ruvopunupo/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Appreciate the response and yes that is a good idea. But I'm having a problem with how to define out of bounds coordinates when the car turns differently onto the grass. Check out the image links. The speed becomes zero at two different positions for the car.

Comment: You are setting  `mod = 0;` in your key up handler at some point, which you use to calc the velocity vector; the result will be 0 for both x and y in doing so. You probably want to separate velocity and position.